# How to setup `cors` on Yesod without scaffold structure?

Tags: haskell, cors, yesod

There is clear doc on enable `CORS` in yesod
https://github.com/yesodweb/yesod-cookbook/blob/master/cookbook/Allowing-WOFF-fonts-to-be-accessed-from-other-domains-%28CORS%29.md#using-wai-cors-package

but it requires to run in a `scaffold` yesod application which has `makeApplication` and `Application.hs`

In my cases, the code base was built not by yesods `scaffold` now try to be exposed as a RESTful service.

```
mkYesod "App" [parseRoutes|
 /Hello HelloR POST OPTIONS
 /version VersionR GET
|]
```

How to add `CORS` support in this case ?

Ref:

- http://hackage.haskell.org/package/wai-cors

Comment: What about putting NGINX in front of your yesod service and enable CORS there?

Comment: You could always just implement the OPTIONS handler yourself. CORS is a simple protocol. It should be about 3 lines of code.

Comment: @daflodedeing in local dev env , it's not neccessary to have a `nginx` setup, eventhough there is one in the production env

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the code how I solve this.

Using `toWaiApp` to extract the `application` instance and wrap it with cors midddle ware.

```
mkYesod "App" [parseRoutes|
 /Hello HelloR POST OPTIONS
 /version VersionR GET
|]

main :: IO ()
main =
   do
     app <- toWaiApp App
     run 8081 $ defaultMiddlewaresNoLogging $ cors (const $ Just $ simpleCorsResourcePolicy { corsOrigins = Nothing , corsMethods = ["OPTIONS", "GET", "PUT", "POST"] , corsRequestHeaders = simpleHeaders }) $ app
```